# CentOS 7 GUI or CLI not loading

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, grub, gui

I have Installed CentOS 7 x86_64 and I forgotten root password. After then I reset the password editing boot grub menu according [How To Reset Root Password On CentOS 7](https://www.unixmen.com/reset-root-password-centos-7/) as follow. But after rebooting machine now I have no GUI or CLI login. What should I do ?

1 – In the boot grub menu select option to edit.

2 – Select Option to edit (e).

3 – Go to the line of Linux 16 and change `ro` with `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh.`

4 – Now press Control+x to start on single user mode.

5 – Now access the system with this command.

```
chroot /sysroot
```

6 – Reset the password.

```
passwd root
```

7 – Update selinux information

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

8 – Exit chroot

```
exit
```

9 – Reboot your system

```
reboot
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Nothing loaded. Stacked the console. This is a VM at Citrix cloud.

Comment: Are you able to see the grub screen again.

Comment: Thanks for correcting mistakes I have been made. No I can't see grub even. @Mongrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use theses steps to solve your issue.

1. Interrupt the boot loader countdown by pressing any key.
2. Move the cursor to the entry that needs to be booted.
3. Press **e** to edit the selected entry.
4. Move the cursor to the kernel command line (the line that starts
   with linux16).
5. Append rd.break (this will break just before control is handed from
   the initramfs to the actual system).

Press Ctrl+x to boot with the changes and execute the following commands.

```
# mount -o remount,rw /sysroot
# chroot /sysroot
# chage -l root
# chage -E -1 root
# passwd root
# touch /.autorelabel
```

Type **`exit`** twice. The first will exit the ***chroot jail***, and the second will exit the ***initramfs debug shell***.